# DRC Vehicle dimensions

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,
We have several issues regarding the DRC vehicle and DRC simulator 2.3 :

a.      Control issues

1. The  DRC vehicle and the golf cart controllers either not respond in the DRC simulator 2.3, or respond very slowly. We reported this issue on answers.gazebosim.org, and an issue was opened in bitbucket.
   http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2254/drc-vehicle-controller-does-not-respond-or/
2. The handbrake command does not respond from the terminal (since DRC simulator 2.3)
3. When trying to manually lower the handbrake with Atlas, the handbrake jumps back to the initial position.
4. There is still no steering wheel in the DRC vehicle. Therefore, it is impossible to drive the vehicle with atlas.

b.      Geometry issues

1. Is it possible to remove the side rails? As you can see the rails block the entrances, and make it very difficult to egress the vehicle.

[view pic in link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z9hvr73yqte8ms0/5.png)

[view pic in link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/arx1zifs3ffeosg/7.png)

2. Lower the height of the seat . The seat is still very high (the seat is at pelvis height) and it makes entering the vehicle very difficult, due to the steering wheel.
3. The upper frame is too small, and when entering the vehicle the broad shoulders of the robot collide with the frame.
   [view pic in link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/96iwriuiy07dxao/6.png)
4. The floor of the vehicle is crowded, there isn't enough "leg room".
   [view pic in link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0gw2zfr6cyk53iy/2.png)

ROBIL Team

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2296/drc-vehicle-dimensions/) by [odedy86](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/297/odedy86/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 19 on 2013-04-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [klowrey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/113/klowrey/) on 2013-04-09**:
I can't answer all your questions but can offer two helpful points. If you set the handbrake value to 0.1, it can get the car moving. This is probably a plugin error where they check for >0.0; so setting it to open doesn't work. Also, there are no side rails in the collision geometry; the Atlas robot cannot collide with it (also no overhead rails, for that matter), so it cannot impede your movement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

These issues have been fixed in recent versions of drcsim and the polaris model in `gazebo_models`.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1